# Authentication without checking the web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I am trying to use ASP.NET forms authentication functionality but it is not possible for me to add every member to the web config file because there may be thousands using the application. I was just wondering is it possible to do the following all within form authentication?

1. User signs in.
2. Flag the user to be authorized.
3. Allow access.

Comment: Where do you keep your users data?

Comment: Hi, I store it in a database but I use a separate entity framework to connect. Thanks for the help i think i can take it from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use Membership provider, with the create user method. [Membershipprovider.createuser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.createuser.aspx)

pseudocode for creating

```
Membership.CreateUser(
 username, password, email,
question, answer, isApproved,
 out flag);
if(flag== MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
    {
// success!  

    }
```

and also you can refer this link to implement

1. [Membership providers](http://odetocode.com/articles/427.aspx)
2. [Membership, Roles, Profiles](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)
3. [Custom Membership provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers)

Answer (score 3):

Use [MemebrshipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) infrastructure.

You can use existing SqlMemebrshipProvider (it uses dedicated SQL DB to keep the data) or roll your own inheriting the base class.

Then install it in Web.config (as described in the same article at the bottom).